# Can assert_equal continues to run even thought some assertions have failed?

Tags: ruby

I am looping through a row of values through assert_equal like this:

```
assert_equal(test[i][4].to_i, featureOne(test[i][1], test[i][2]),test[i][0])
```

I was just wondering if assert_equal is designed to stop at the 1st occurrence when test failed?

For example, if the second test failed, the rest of the tests will not be executed?

Is there any library that I can use that continue to the next test though the current test has failed?

Answer (score 0):

of course not, if the second test failed, the rest of the tests will  be executed.let me give you an example:

```
class Test
  def add a, b
    a + b
  end
  def minus a, b
    a - b
  end
end

require "minitest/autorun"
class TestTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_ad
    a = Test.new
    assert_equal 2, a.add(1,1)
    assert_equal 2, a.add(1,2)
  end

  def test_minus
    a = Test.new
    assert_equal 0, a.minus(1,1)
    assert_equal 2, a.minus(1,2)
  end

end
```

and you will get the output:

```
Run options: --seed 61427

# Running:

FF

Finished in 0.001360s, 1470.5223 runs/s, 2941.0446 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
TestTest#test_ad :
Expected: 2
  Actual: 3


  2) Failure:
TestTest#test_minu :
Expected: 2
  Actual: -1

2 runs, 4 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: I modified the code and cause the first assert_equal in test_add to fail and the second assert_equal didn't get executed.  Same behaviour was happening in  test_minus. Which brings me back to my original point, once an assert_equal fails, the rest of the assert_equal test within the method won't be executed.   Interesting point, I thought you would want to continue the rest of the tests to find out what else has failed.  Any thoughts?